# Error while consuming wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I created a wcf application library with no modification from the original example and I hosted it in IIS. It's on a remote computer and using chrome i can see that the service is up and running but if  i try to create a config file using

> svcutil.exe http://`IP_HERE`/serv/WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1.svc?wsdl

i receive the following error.

[image]

I think that it has something to do with the application pool. What do you think?

My default config: http://pastebin.com/a355LcWp

Comment: Using Alt+Space (or by clicking the icon) you can select and then copy (Enter) command prompt text. Paste this text in your favorite text editor, then paste the relevant part in your favorite web search engine to find the solution to which the answer I'm sure resides somewhere on this site.

Comment: You sent it SOAP and it expected plain text. Have you googled how to change that?

Comment: The thing is that i didn't mess with the example. It's the default.

Comment: Can you post your service web.config? Looks like you havent enabled metadata endpoint.

Comment: I added the config settings.

Comment: This `svcutil.exe http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/?wsdl` by the way works.

Answer (score 0):

After checking your service config file I found that you are hosting service on port 8733 which is mentioned in base address value. You need to make sure that you include this port number while accessing wsdl.